# Gson populating trouble

Tags: android, gson, retrofit

```
VkUsersResponce qwe = gsonBuilder.create().fromJson("{\"response\":[{\"id\":1,\"first_name\":\"Павел\",\"last_name\":\"Дуров\",\"sex\":2}]}", VkUsersResponce.class);

public class VkUsersResponce {
    @Getter
    @Setter
    private List<VkUser> responce;
}

public class VkUser {
    @Getter
    @Setter
    private int sex;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    private long id;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    private String firstName;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    private String lastName;
}
```

`qwe` is actually `null`.

Comment: Write some more lines and at the end a question what you want to have and actually you said it is null. So just type some more about the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You JSON field names and java object names must match.

From your JSON -- "response\" with an 's'.
From your object -- "responce" with a 'c'.

Either change your field to be "response", or use [`SerializedName`](https://google.github.io/gson/apidocs/com/google/gson/annotations/SerializedName.html) like --

```
@SerializedName("response")
private List<VkUser> responce;
```

You will have a similar issue with `firstName` vs `first_name`.  You may be able to use [`GsonBuilder.setFieldNamingPolicy`](https://google.github.io/gson/apidocs/com/google/gson/GsonBuilder.html#setFieldNamingPolicy%28com.google.gson.FieldNamingPolicy%29) to avoid annotating every field.  See [`LOWER_CASE_WITH_UNDERSCORES`](https://google.github.io/gson/apidocs/com/google/gson/FieldNamingPolicy.html#LOWER_CASE_WITH_UNDERSCORES)

Comment: Yes i've found this mistake yesterday, thanks for the reply.